# Como melhorar esse código jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou aprendendo jQuery e nem sempre sei exatamente como desenvolver o código de forma mais limpa, semântica, vou acabar aprendendo. Como eu poderia melhorar esse código?

```
$("#click_apoio").on('click', function( evento ){

    evento.preventDefault();

    if( $("#institucional").hasClass('desativado') ){

        $("#institucional").removeClass('desativado');
        $("#institucional").addClass('ativado');
        $("#parceiros").removeClass('ativado');
        $("#parceiros").addClass('desativado');

    }

});
```

Comment: Você também pode pensar numa outra estrutura... você ta usando duas classes: ativado e desativado... se usasse uma classe só, você usaria ao inves de removeClass e addClass.. o método toggleClass... e adaptaria o css para atender a essa estrutura...

Comment: Concordo Pedro com o que falou !!!

Comment: Cara, as vezes tornar o código mais limpo, não significa ter menos quantidade de linha, e sim deixar ele legível. O seu código está bom e da pra ser entendido. Outro fator importante é verificar o demais se possui algum código repetido, para separar em functions

Comment: @EricoSouza exatamente! Como comentei abaixo, não tem nada de "não profissional" nesse código, ele esta bom, da pra enteder perfeitamente o que esta fazendo!

Comment: Obrigado a todos por acharem a questão interessante a ponto de haver um pequeno debate.

Comment: Uma dúvida... há a necessidade de jQuery na sua função? Essa pergunta foi somente a nível de aprendizagem? Porque ao meu ver, poderia muito bem atingir o mesmo objetivo somente com javaScript

Comment: Então @MarceloBonifazio eu faço parte do grupo de pessoas que aprendem jQuery sem realmente saber Javascript. Estudo Javascript mas não a ponto de priorizá-lo em detrimento do jQuery. :)

Comment: Sim, é valido, mas tenha em mente que usar jQuery afeta na performance da página, mesmo que pouco, apesar que com jQuery você tem acesso a muitas coisas úteis que somente com javaScript puro fica mais complicado fazer

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4210/eu-sou-f%C3%A3-mas-infelizmente-esta-ferramenta-inibe-as-participa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-porqu%C3%AA-tem-qu

Comment: Assim como está eu não votava para fechar, alias retirei o voto. Embora continue a não gostar da maioria das perguntas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como boas práticas em javascript, é interessante criar variáveis de cada elemento que será manipulado, para evitar muitos acessos a àrvore DOM. Veja estas modificações que fiz no código:

```
$(function() {

  $("#click_apoio").on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var $institucional = $("#institucional"),
      $parceiros = $("#parceiros");

    if($institucional.hasClass('desativado')) {

        $institucional.removeClass('desativado')
          .addClass('ativado');

        $parceiros.removeClass('ativado')
          .addClass('desativado');    
    }    

  }); 

});
```

Sobre as modificações:

- Adicionei uma função anônima do jQuery (`$(function){...});`) para evitar que o script seja carregado antes do objeto jQuery existir na página;
- Criei variáveis para cada elemento a ser manipulado, evitando acessos desnecessários à árvore DOM;
- Aninhei funções em cada elemento, para organizar o código e ficar mais legível (Ex: `$institucional.removeClass('desativado').addClass('ativado');`);

Comment: Legal isso hein @Henrique !!!

Comment: Esse código tá me dando um reload na página hein ....

Comment: Dá uma olhada no console da página. Provavelmente eu deva ter errado na hora de digitar o código.

Comment: Fiz um exemplo bem tosco só pra mostrar que pode ser usada a função `toggleClass` também.

https://jsfiddle.net/rm5d55bf/1/

Answer (score 7):

Tem como melhor seu código usando uma outra lógica, por exemplo, se existe apenas dois estados `ativado` e `desativado`, logo você pode omitir o "desativado" deixando o elemento padrão com esse comportamento, e alterar apenas se houver a `class="ativado"`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$("#click_apoio").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#institucional, #parceiros").toogleClass('ativado');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#click_apoio").on('click', function( evento ){
    evento.preventDefault();
    if($("#institucional").hasClass('desativado')){
        $("#institucional").removeClass('desativado').addClass('ativado');
        $("#parceiros").removeClass('ativado').addClass('desativado');
    }
});
```

Bom deu pra diminuir um pouco de linha.

Comment: Tinha tentado concatenar as instruções mas não tinha dado certo. Obrigado

Comment: Mas você só removeu as linhas, não melhorou o código em nada,

Comment: rsrsrsrs .... dá a sua opção @Gerep !!!!

Comment: @MarcosVinicius É ai que tá, não tem nada de "não profissinal" nesse código, jQuery é assim!

Comment: Obrigado @Gerep por me avisar que não sou tão novato assim !!!! rsrsrs :)

Comment: Não tem mais nada há fazer no código @Gerep, está certinho :)
A única coisa que ele pode fazer se for referenciar muito esse ID no seu código é criar variáveis para deixar ele mais "inteligível"

Comment: @Danilo, sim, eu entendi e sem dúvida sua sugestão é muito válida mas eu não entendo o motivo de acharem que não esta "inteligível" o suficiente, o código esta super claro e direto, na minha opnião, não vejo necessidade alguma de alterar :)

Comment: Por exemplo, acho que foi útil para o @MarcosVinicius, pois ele não estava conseguindo concatenar.

Answer (score 4):

Não acredito que tenha algum problema com o seu código, ele não está menos profissional porque não parece complexo ou por ter várias linhas.

Muitas vezes algoritmos bonitinhos são mais propensos a erros e mais difíceis de debugar, além de também serem mais difíceis de implementar e entender, caso outro programador precise dele.

Sempre foco em desenvolver algoritmos simples e bem claros, mesmo que isso o torne verboso (existem outros fatores a se considerar).

Resumindo e utilizando a [filosofia Unix](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html):

> Rule of Clarity: Clarity is better than cleverness.

Comment: Concordo com você @Gerep

Comment: @MarcosVinicius que bom =) Depois dê uma olhada no link que enviei na resposta, é bem interessante e para mim é uma referência.

Comment: Concordo que o que importa no final é um código limpo e de fácil entendimento. Concordo também que sempre há outros fatores a se considerar e, em se tratando de web, o desempenho do código também é bem importante, pois os acessos à sites esta cada vez mais sendo feito por dispositivos móveis, por isso a importância de buscar o melhor desempenho.

Comment: @HenriqueSchreiner com toda razão. Existe também uma regra na filosofia Unix que toca um pouco nesse assunto: `Rule 2. Measure. Don't tune for speed until you've measured, and even then don't unless one part of the code overwhelms the rest.`

Comment: Como aquela expressão: _Matar formiga com bazuca!_